# std::sort on a c-style string, without copying the string

Tags: c++, c, string

I've run into a strange, and very specific issue. As some background, I need to support some legacy code that's passing around a lot of large c-style strings. Since these get pretty gigantic, I want to avoid unnecessarily copying that data, which would include copy constructing std::strings just for one operation.

I want to use std::sort on these strings, but they obviously lack iterators. However, according to the documentation for std::sort, I should just be able to pass in two pointers for any contiguous random access memory, but it isn't working with my c-style string

Basically it's like this:

```
char* foo = "test string";
std::sort(foo, foo + 11);    // access violation occurs
```

However:

```
char foo[] = "test string";
std::sort(foo, foo + 11);    // perfect fine, sorted correctly
```

This is extra confusing to me, because as far as I know, char* and char[] are essentially the same. Why does char* break, while char[] succeeds? How can I pass a c-style string into an STL algorithm?

Comment: That's because the literal `"test string"` is read-only.

Comment: `char* foo = "test string";` should give you a compilation warning/error.

Comment: "but they obviously lack iterators" ... pointers are obviously iterators

Comment: *"because as far as I know, char* and char[] are essentially the same."* Not really, no.

Comment: Also, that was not hard to google. Please do some research before asking.

Comment: If you are sorting the characters in a string, as opposed to a vector of strings, you should consider a counting sort, which could be a lot faster on long​ strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char* foo = "test string";
```

This is a pointer to a **string literal**,  which is stored in read-only memory, thus you cannot modify/sort it.

---

Your code should be giving you a warning, similar to this:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ g++ -Wall main.cpp 
main.cpp:3:17: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated
      [-Wc++11-compat-deprecated-writable-strings]
    char* foo = "test string";
                ^
```

---

Please read: [What is the difference between char s[] and char *s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)